Obscure 80s cartoon
It’s a cartoon from the 80s that has flying ships that are hidden in a barn or something like that. I seem to remember the ships are flown by a team. Some ships may have been round, I was around 7or 8 when I saw it. It was a week day cartoon

Can you tell us anything more about the plot, characters, or the world the story is set in? And are there any similar cartoons that you can rule out?

Was this definitely a cartoon (as in animation?) Or could it have been, say, pictures in a book? If the latter, I suspect it might be John Noakes's Flight of the Magic Clog  (see artwork at https://www.abebooks.co.uk/Flight-Magic-Clog-Noakes-John-Fontana/11096880257/bd#&gid=1&pid=1)

Are the "flying ships" like sailing ships, or cargo ships, or not like ocean-going ships at all?  If they have masts, how many?  Only on top or in various directions?  Are they made of wood, steel, or something else?  How big is "a team?"  Are they human?  All male or mixed?  Do they wear a uniform?  What colour is it?  Why are they hiding?

@Dan: Any info on what the ships might have looked like? Sailing ships? Rocket ships? Flying saucers? Hovercraft?

Do you remember what language, country, or network you might have watched it on?

And do you know if the crew was predominantly of one race? Mixed? Aliens? Robots?

Were you 7 or 8 in the 1920's? 50's? 90's? Your age only helps in context.

Could this be Dinosaucers? Or is it definitely humans on the ships?

Dan in the absence of more details (or a reopened question) there are compilations on YouTube of all 1980s cartoons or 1970s that may help you.
